# React setState not updating state in AG Grid onCellValueChanged callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I am using Ag Grid in my React.js project.
I want to increase the `count` value if the cell value changes. I am passing my `handleChange` function to `onCellValueChanged` callBack. Every time cell value changes it triggers my `handleChange` function, but the issue is `count` value is always 0 regardless updating it through `setState(count + 1)`. Can anyone help with this?

I have posted an example on StackBlitz to reproduce this issue :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-react-hello-world-zmsvf5?embed=1&file=index.js

[image: minimilastic example of this issue]

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a workaround [on ag-grid issue](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/3114).

Basically, you need to use function callback when calling `setCount` so that the actual state is used.

```
function handleChange() {
  setCount(count => count + 1);
}
```

[Updated code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-react-hello-world-fseq1j?embed=1&file=index.js)

Comment: This solution works but I have a question, why we require to use previous state and why is it not updating directly. What is the main reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is to execute de loading function without useEffect. It causes too many re-renders because in each setRowData, the component render again.

This is the solution:

```
    function loadDataFromServer() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setRowData([{ make: "Toyota" }, { make: "Toyota" }, { make: "Toyota" }]);
    }, 1000);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
  }, [rowData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadDataFromServer();
  }, []);

  // function handleChange() {
  //   //here Count will always remain 0 (the value provided initially)
  //   console.log("Count => ", count);
  //   setCount(count + 1);
  // }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Count Changes: {count}</h1>
      <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 400 }}>
        <AgGridReact rowData={rowData}>
          <AgGridColumn
            field="make"
            editable={true}
            // onCellValueChanged={handleChange}
          />
        </AgGridReact>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: It won't work. because you are not capturing the cell changes.

Comment: also, you are invoking loadDataFromServer() in useEffect hook without any dependencies. it will load data from server every time UI renders.